# Python pandas :cannot grab more than 100 rows at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm developing a screener of sorts and trying to load this specific URL:
https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MOTHERSUMI.BO/history?period1=1548115200&period2=1582329600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

I'm loading the dataFrame like so

```
req = requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MOTHERSUMI.BO/history?period1=1548115200&period2=1582329600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
df = pd.read_html(req.content)
df = df[0]
df.to_csv(<somefile>)
```

But When i open the CSV i see that data is restricted to just 100Rows only and always.
Even when i print the df as is(without pushing into a csv) i still get only 100rows.

I"m not sure if i'm missing something or there is some other issue.
Any help?

Wondering if there is a RACE between the page getting fully loaded VS when pandas grabs the data off it.

Answer (score 0):

You have only the first 100 rows that are loaded when requesting the page. The following rows are loaded by javascript when scrolling which cannot be done by requests.

[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) may do what you want.

Comment: Actually i saw another approach.
this link:https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MOTHERSUMI.BO/history?period1=1519344000&period2=1582416000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

actually has another link called 'Download data'. i'm trying everything i know to just download it directly but ,it just isn't work.
tried with BS and selenium i dont see that 'href' at all.
Any idea how i can get it?